# Random Fermion Hopping Model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, disorder

Consider a random, all to all, complex fermion hopping model on $N$ sites with quenched (Gaussian) disorder, that has a well defined large $N$ limit (aka the SYK2 model). So, we start with free fermions in this model and after disorder averaging we lose the quasiparticles in this model. Is there a nice physical way to understand this result? Or should this simply be taken as a mathematical consequence of the Schwinger Dyson equations and that's all there is to it?

Example/Reference: Look at equation A3 on page 25 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1706.07803).

Comment: Are you sure we lose quasiparticles? After averaging which quantities?

Comment: After averaging over the Gaussian disorder. For instance, consider the disorder averaged single particle Green function: the Schwinger Dyson in this case is simply $\Sigma(\tau) \propto G(\tau)$, where $G(\tau)$ is the renormalized Green function, which eliminates the pole in single particle Green function.

Comment: I think a handwaving explanation is that the low-energy spectrum is dominated Goldstone modes from spontaneously breaking down to $SL(2, \mathbf{R})$ symmetry (that pick up a small mass due to explicit symmetry breaking).

Comment: @d_b Umm, not sure, how would one argue that the breaking of the emergent reparametrization & gauge symmetry should make the quasiparticles vanish? For instance, in neutral superfluids, breaking of the global gauge symmetry and considering Goldstone mode fluctuations in phase still retains the Bogoliubov quasiparticles (they are massless but there)...

Comment: In contrast to your statement, the paper appears to say (near the top of p.5) that for $q=2$, that is the random hopping case which is calculated in eq. (A3), the SYK model has Fermi liquid behavior and quasiparticles at low temperature. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: The first sections of this thesis give a nice introduction to the SYK model, which also appears to be consistent with this understanding: http://qpt.physics.harvard.edu/theses/Wenbo_Fu_thesis.pdf

Comment: @Rococo Thanks. Indeed, that's what they always say. It's in Sachdev's papers, talks and Wenbo Fu's thesis as well. But if I look at the retarded Green function of SYK2 (in frequency domain), I can't find a zero of the denominator, let alone a pole. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Thanks! I understand your question now.